# Angularjs expressions - How complex can they be?

Tags: angularjs

I have a json object that is a serialization of a list so is just an array of json objects.

Can I use the like of [JSONSelect](http://jsonselect.org/#overview) to bind a value?

If not then how can I bind id.name where id==2 to a dom element?

```
{"data": [ { "id":1, "name":"Rob"}, {"id":2, "name": "John"} ] }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?  What does the html you are trying to bind code look like?

Comment: In practice what I have is 2 'lists'; a set of 'questions' that are rendered a html and a set of 'current answers'. There is a reference in the question data to the answer value and I need to bind the answer value to the question element. The problem is that the 2 lists are not in the same order and questions can be repeated (on separate tabs).

Comment: I have found that by turning the answer list into a dictionary helps but I was interested to find out if I could bind say, "data[id=1].name" or using something like JSONSelect ".data .id:val("1") ~ .name"; but I need two-way binding.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some proccess on your json data:

```
function getNameForId(data, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].id === id) return data[i].name;
    }
}
```

then, you can bind the reslut.

see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ronapelbaum/x8x5axvn/)